# Почему так работает for?

Tags: java, retrofit

Получаю данные ретрофитом с апи.

Собственно получаю вот такой json:

```
{
  "Global": {
    "item1": 1
    "item2": 2
  },
  "Countries": [
    {
      "Country": "ALA Aland Islands",
      ...other attributes
    },
    {
      "Country": "Afghanistan",
      ...other attributes


@GET("summary")
Call<SummaryResponse<TotalStatsModel, List<CountryModel>>> getData();
```

Retrofit в методе onResponse возвращает мне список моделей CountryModel, но при попытке перебора через foreach

```
for (CountryModel country : countries) {
```

получаю ошибку

```
Incompatible types. Required: Object Found: CountryModel.
```

Если написать

```
for (Object country : countries) {
```

То у IDE не видит методов модели, хотя `county instanceof CountryModel == true`

Почему это так работает? Как мне правильно перебрать список моделей CountryModel?

Comment: А вы уверены что даны смапились в данную модель?

Comment: @UKRman как я могу это проверить?

Comment: Дебагом, посмотреть состоит ли массив countries из объектов CountryModal,

Comment: @UKRman там точно список из CountryModel, я проверял

Comment: можно перебрать как Object, а после в теле цикла сделать приведение типов к CountryModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for (Object country : countries) {
    if( country instanceof CountryModel ) {
        CountryModel countryModel = (CountryModel)country;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: работает! спасибо. А можете вкратце объяснить почему так?

Comment: @СергейО Из-за "сужения" спецификации объекта от типа CountryModel в Object. В суженном объекте остается только информация об исходном объекте (имя типа), но не его функции ( а только функции Object), а после приведения "вниз" (как принято на диаграммах UML), спецификация как бы расширяется до истинного изначального объекта.

Comment: да, я понимаю что где-то видимо происходит cast в Object и там нет методов CountryModel, но кто это делает? GSON?

Comment: @СергейО а вот это вопрос к Retrofit :)